# How to format JavaScript generated HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to make a function which can generate tables from the data passed. The data is supposed  to be in this format:

```js
let tableContent = [
  [
    {
      type: "td",
      content: "Hello!",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      type: "td",
      content: "Hello!",
    },
  ],
];
```

Here the entire array is one table, arrays inside it are rows, and objects inside them are data for each cell inside the row.

The problem is that when I use this function on this data:

```js
function makeTable(tableArray) {
  //Entire Table
  let tableTemplate;
  let tableContent = "";

  //row level variables
  let rowTemplate;
  let rowContent = "";

  //cell level variables
  let cellType;
  let cellContent;
  let cellTemplate;

  //running function for each row
  tableArray.forEach((row) => {
    //running function for each cell
    row.forEach((cell) => {
      cellType = cell.type || "td";
      if (cellType !== "td" && cellType !== "th")
        return console.error(
          `Error: The type of a cell must be either "td" or "th" you passed "${cellType}"!`
        );
      cellContent = cell.content;
      cellTemplate = `<${cellType}>${cellContent}</${cellType}>`;
      rowContent += cellTemplate;
    });

    rowTemplate = `<tr>${rowContent}</tr>`;
    tableContent += rowTemplate;
    rowContent = ""
  });

  tableTemplate = `<table>${tableContent}</table>`;
  return tableTemplate;
}
//this function outputs:
//<table><tr><td>Hello!</td></tr><tr><td>Hello!</td></tr></table>
//if used on the above data
```

The table is formed on one single line. I want that the code generated is nicely indented and easily readable. I know that this is not important as the main functionality of the function is to generate tables not code. But still so that it is easier to understand the generated code, I want it to be readable. My question is how can apply indentations to the generated code?

Thanks for reading my query!

Comment: `\t` will create a tab, `\r\n` will create a newline

Comment: I tried messing around with them but for more complex tables this is messing it up

Comment: @Jamiec basically it isn't working for me

Comment: Define: Isn't working. Do you mean you're trying to output the string to the console but you dont get tabs/ line feeds?

Comment: Do you know `Document.createElement()`? it would really help you out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @Jamiec basically it is putting tabs here and there and the code isn't actually getting that formatted. Like it just scrambles things I played around with them but then I gave up

Comment: @AdilBimzagh sure that will work but I want to generate code and not really make elements in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `\t` for tabs to indent (or a couple of spaces if you prefer) and `\r\n` for newlines.

Something like this for example:

```js
function makeTable(tableArray) {
  //Entire Table
  let tableTemplate;
  let tableContent = "";

  //row level variables
  let rowTemplate;
  let rowContent = "";

  //cell level variables
  let cellType;
  let cellContent;
  let cellTemplate;

  //running function for each row
  tableArray.forEach((row) => {
    //running function for each cell
    row.forEach((cell) => {
      cellType = cell.type || "td";
      if (cellType !== "td" && cellType !== "th")
        return console.error(
          `Error: The type of a cell must be either "td" or "th" you passed "${cellType}"!`
        );
      cellContent = cell.content;
      cellTemplate = `\t\t<${cellType}>${cellContent}</${cellType}>\r\n`;
      rowContent += cellTemplate;
    });

    rowTemplate = `\t<tr>\r\n${rowContent}\t</tr>\r\n`;
    tableContent += rowTemplate;
    rowContent = ""
  });

  tableTemplate = `<table>\r\n${tableContent}</table>`;
  return tableTemplate;
}

let tableContent = [
  [
    {
      type: "td",
      content: "Hello!",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      type: "td",
      content: "Hello!",
    },
  ],
];

console.log(makeTable(tableContent))
```

Comment: I don't think I have another option. I just wanted the code formatting to be done by something else instead of manual. Just so that I can confirm that the code will always format correctly but still this works so thanks!